# Understanding Energy consumption - 3-phase Power Meter - Active (forward, reverse) and Apparent

Tags: energy

I'm looking at 3-phase power data from a machine using a Fluke monitor. I've got 'Energy Analyze Plus' software which then calculates lots of interesting things and I'm trying to understand what I need!

I want to determine what the energy used is by the machine which would be billed by the utility. This is for non-residential use. I'm worried I've completely misinterpreted what parameter I need to look at so any clarification would be helpful!

I had thought that the Active Energy was what was used by the machine and the Apparent Energy was what was drawn by the utility which would be higher to account for losses in the system.

However I've also now come across Forward and Reverse Active Energy. I'd been looking at the Total Active Energy compared to the Total Apparent Energy and assumed the differences were due to loses such as harmonics which could be described by the Power Factor. So I'd thought that the Total Apparent Energy would indicate what was billed from the utility. However I'm now v confused with the forward and reverse Active Energies and whether this is really what I should be looking at.

Thank you for reading, apologies for probably a very basic question as I'm not an engineer!

Comment: this does help yes, but I still am not clear which value (Active or Apparent) power is most relevant for me. I'm in an industry environment so just looking at Active doesnt seem appropriate as this doesnt look at loses due to PF. I want to look at the energy cost in an industry of running the machine, and from that article it looks like industries get charged for reactive power loses as well but I'm not completely clear on how this is done. Could Apparent energy be a possible measure to estimate costings of the machine or is this an overestimate?